# ¿Cómo cargar foto de perfil de Google+?

Tags: android, google+, google-plus

tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo integrado el servicio Google Sign In con mi aplicación y una vez un usuario se ha identificado, puedo obtener la Uri perteneciente a su foto de perfil, pero cuando intento establecer esa imagen en algún ImageView, me salta el siguiente error:

resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: "aquí iría la URI de la foto de perfil del usuario"

Alguna idea de cómo poder cargar esa imagen? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Como estas "estableciendo" esa imagen? ImageView no tiene soporte para cargar una imagen desde una url, tenes que descargarla primero

Comment: @SirKuryaki estoy estableciéndola utilizando el setImageUri, cómo podría descargarla?? Gracias por responder

Comment: Te recomiendo usar una libreria, como por ej Picasso. Agregame un ejemplo del código que estas utilizando y yo lo modifico.

Comment: @SirKuryaki muchas gracias, aquí tienes: ImageView fotoUsuario = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.menuFotoUsuario);
                fotoUsuario.setImageURI(Uri.parse(sesionActual.getFoto()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método [setImageURI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) solo funciona con URIs locales. Te recomiendo que utilices una librería para poder mostrar imágenes desde una URL en un ImageView.

Podes utilizar [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) por ej:

Agrega la siguiente dependencia en tu archivo gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

y cambia las lineas del código por las siguientes

```
 ImageView fotoUsuario = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.menuFotoUsuario); 

 Picasso.with(this).load(sesionActual.getFoto()).into(fotoUsuario);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya me funciona!!

Comment: me alegro! no te olvides de aceptar mi respuesta! @Alber1512

Comment: Soy muy nuevo aquí, cómo hago eso? jajaja

Comment: Fijate este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers @Alber1512